# Bigcommerce API request to fetch Orders with timezone issue(PHP)

Tags: php, api, timezone, bigcommerce

In my bigcommerce dashboard, there is this date: 22nd Mar 2015 for order id 172, but while fetching from API I get this date: Sat, 21 Mar 2015 17:42:01 +0000 for the same order id 172.

I want to get the same order date from API request as this is appearing on my bigcommerce dashboard.

This is a timezone issue, how can we solve this problem by using PHP?

Anyone with the bigcommerce logic there?

Comment: Do you have a *time* to go alongside the date of March 22nd? What time zone is that meant to be in? (The API is giving you a very specific date/time, including UTC offset...) The question is too vague to answer at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Here is my bigcommerce timezone settings: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0204oxpo00

Comment: @JonSkeet Why do you think this is vague? this is the real problem and i am also suffered with the same issue. if you have answer then you can comment, its not for entertain you guys

Comment: @Pus: There's too much information missing.

Comment: @Krishna: Okay, so now we know the time zone you're interested in (please add that to the question) - so are you just trying to convert the date/time you've received from the API into that time zone in PHP? If so, it's unclear that this is really bigcommerce-specific at all, and I can probably find a duplicate question somewhere. (Or just read http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Skeet: Thanks! I found the solution for this issue.

I just added following line at the top of my script.
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Darwin');

Here, Australia/Darwin is from my bigcommerce dashboard (Date Settings).

But i have set this statically, i tried API request to get default timezone for my store on bogcommerce using: $ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();

It just get the result like:

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-03-23 08:52:48.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)

I want to get the timezone from bigcommerce store dynamically. 
If anybody have an idea about this??

Thanks!